# Why do I have an error while running Manim inside PyCharm?

Tags: python, import, pycharm, manim

I have installed Manim with Git Clone from PyCharm Terminal

Manim is installed in `C:\Users\fransua\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\ManimOfficial\manim`

In my main.py

```py
from manimlib.imports import *
```

When I run main.py :

```
**C:\Users\fransua\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\ManimOfficial\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/fransua/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/ManimOfficial/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fransua\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\ManimOfficial\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from manimlib.imports import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manimlib.imports'**
```

And there is manimlib directory inside manim.

Comment: Where is your main? Did you make sure that the `manim` folder is in `sys.path` (probably by calling `pip install .`)

Comment: Actually after the `git clone` I did `pip install -e .` inside the manim directory

Comment: Are you sure you got the pip for the correct venv? Does pycharm show the manim projcet in the overview when you go to Interepter settings?

Comment: Actually I have changed the `from manimlib.imports import *` to `from manimlib import *` as there was no imports folders. Now the message became : _'manim' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme ex�cutable ou un fichier de commandes._

Answer (score 0):

Finally I switched to the github of Manim Community and it works fine with a simple :

```
pip install manim
```